# Написать sql запрос, который посчитает метрику качества прогноза R2 (коэффициент детерминации) для каждого артикула/магазина

Tags: sql

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в этой задаче

Есть две таблицы:

S1 - данные по прогнозам продаж на уровне артикул/магазин/ неделя.
date_-  неделя (в таблице указывается воскресенье недели),  colormodel- артикул товара, id_obj  - номер магазина, fcst - прогноз в штуках.

S2 - таблица с данными по фактическим продажам на уровне артикул/магазин/ неделя.
date_ -  неделя (в таблице указывается воскресенье недели) , colormodel - артикул товара, id_obj -номер магазина, qty - продажи в штуках.

- В данных таблицы S2 не хранятся строки с неделями, когда были нулевые продажи.
  В таблице S1 хранятся все строки артикул/магазин/неделя (нулевые прогнозы записываются).

Задача: написать sql запрос, который посчитает метрику качества прогноза R2 (коэффициент детерминации) для каждого артикула/магазина.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итоговая таблица должна содержать следующие столбцы: colormodel , id_obj , R2 (коэффициент детерминации).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажите, какая у вас база данных? И что конкретно вызывает у вас затруднение?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin Вся Бд это и есть две таблицы. Сложность в том что я запутался в самом запросе. У меня получилось нечто подобное, но оно естественно не работает:
SELECT DISTINCT 1 -((SELECT SUM(yx) FROM (SELECT POWER(SUM(QTY) - SUM(FCST),2) AS yx FROM S1 LEFT JOIN S2 ON S1.DATE_ = S2.DATE_ GROUP BY DATE_))/(SELECT SUM(yy) FROM (SELECT POWER(SUM(QTY) - SELECT AVG(QTY) FROM (SELECT SUM(QTY) AS QTY FROM S2 GROUP BY DATE_),2) AS yy FROM S2 GROUP BY DATE_)) FROM S1